# Minimizing a functional in the Sobolev space $H_0^1$

Tags: functional-analysis, optimization, sobolev-spaces, normed-spaces, weak-convergence

I am trying to show that, given $f \in H^{-1}(U)$, there exists a unique $u \in H_0^1(U)$ such that:
$$\int_U \nabla u\cdot\nabla v \, \mathrm{d}x= \langle f,v \rangle_{H^{-1}} \, , \quad \forall \, v \in H_0^1(U) \, .$$
To this end, I define the functional $J \colon H_0^1(U) \to \mathbb{R}$ by:
$$J(v):=\int_U \left\| \nabla v \right\|^2 \, \mathrm{d}x- \langle f,v \rangle_{H^{-1}}.$$
Then I would like to do the following:

1. Show that $J(v)$ is bounded from below;
2. Show that there is a weakly convergent sequence whose limit in $H_0^1(U)$ minimises $J$ (hence the inf is achieved);
3. Show that this limit satisfies the problem and it is unique.

Number 3 is quite easy, but I am stuck on 1 and 2. I am not sure how to proceed. So far I have oly been able to use the definition of $\|\cdot\|_{H^{-1}}$ to get:
$$J(v) \geq \int_U \left\| \nabla v \right\|^2 \, \mathrm{d}x- \|f \|_{H^{-1}} \|v\|_{H_0^1} \, .$$
Any pointers would be very helpful.

P.S.: I am aware that this could be shown by applying Lax-Milgram but I need to take this direct approach.

Comment: what are $\langle.,.\rangle_{H^{-1}}$ and $||.||_{H^{-1}}$ ?

Comment: The first is the pairing of an element of $H^{-1}$ and $H^1_0$ and it corresponds to the inner product on $L^2$ if $f \in L^2 \subset H^{-1}$, while the second one is the norm on $H^{-1}$ and it is given by: $$\|f\|_{H^{-1}}=\sup_{v \in H^1_0\setminus \{ 0\} } \frac{\langle f,v \rangle}{\|v\|_{H^1_0}}$$.

Comment: so you meant $H^{-1}$ is $(H_0^1)^*$ (the dual of $H^1_0$) the space of bounded linear functionals $H^1_0 \to \mathbb{C}$

Comment: Yes but $(H_0^1)^*$ can be misleading as $H_0^1$ is a Hilbert space with respect to the inner product: $$(u,v) = \left( \int \nabla u \cdot \nabla v \, \mathrm{d} x + \int uv \, \mathrm{d}x \right)^{\frac{1}{2}}$$ and hence $(H_0^1)^* = H_0^1$.
The dual space $H^{-1}$ is considered with respect to the $L^2$ inner product instead of the one defined above and hence:
$$H_0^1 \subset L^2 = (L^2)^* \subset H^{-1} \, .$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $U$ be a bounded smooth domain and $\|u\|=\|\nabla u\|_2$ the usual norm in $H_0^1(U)$.

1) $J$ is coercive.

Indeed, we have that $$J(u)\ge \|u\|^2-\|f\|_{H^{-1}}\|u\|,$$

which implies that $J$ is coercive.

2) $J$ is weakly lower semicontinuous, or equivalently, if $u_n\to u$ weak then, $J(u)\le \liminf J(u_n)$.

In fact, if $u_n\to u$ weak then $\langle f,u_n\rangle\to \langle f,u\rangle$, because $f$ is a continuous linear functional in $H_0^1(U)$. On the other hand, the norm function $\|u\|$ is always weakly lower semicontinuous, therefore

\begin{equation} \label{eq1}
\begin{split}
J(u) & = \int |\nabla u|^2-\langle f,u\rangle \\
 & \le \liminf \int |\nabla u_n|^2-\lim \langle f,u_n\rangle \\
& \le \liminf \left(\int |\nabla u_n|^2-\langle f,u_n\rangle\right) \\
& = \liminf J(u_n).
\end{split}
\end{equation}

Now you can combine 1) with 2) to guarantee the existence of a minimum for $J$. Also, the strictly convexity of $J$ will imply that the minimum is unique.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

Comment: You are welcome.